When a minimal left module is not totally isotropic
Let $A=\operatorname{End}_D(V)$ for some division algebra $D$ and some $D$-module of the right $V$. For any involution $\ast$ in $A$, we can choose an involution $\sigma$ on $D$ of the same type as $\ast$ (in particular it restricts to the same automorphism of the center), and then there is a hermitian form $h: V\times V\to D$ over $(D,\sigma)$ such that $\ast$ is the adjoint involution with respect to $h$.
$V$ is totally isotropic or $h(v,v)=0$ for all $v \in V$ if the form $h$ is alternating and so if the involution is symplectic. However, according to this answer, Capitam Lama added the condition that $A$ is split. Why does there not exist $v$ such that $h(v,v)\ne 0$ only if $A$ is split with symplectic involution?
